# Is it possible to revert recent changes?

Tags: mercurial

I've made unwanted changes to several files recently. Is it possible to revert them based on the time (for example revert all changes made in last 10 minutes)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Option 1: Rollback or strip

In case you already commit (and not pushed) some of the unwanted changes, it is easy:

```
$ hg strip <firts-unwanted-revision>
```

This requires the [<del>`mq`</del>](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/MqExtension#Configuration)[`strip` extension to be enabled](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/StripExtension).

Alternatively check if the `rollback` command is sufficient for your case.

#### Option 2: Revert selected files only

Otherwise you can only revert files to the state of the last commit. Mercurial (as Git, SVN, and most other version control systems) only tracks changes when you commit. Everything in between is out of Mercurial's control. That's why it is generally best to commit early and often.

However, you could make use of the modification time of your files and only revert those that have been touched in the last 10 minutes. Be aware that this reverts *all* changes per file, i.e. also changes made in these files more than 10 minutes ago. It only safes your correctly edited files where the last change has been more than 10 minutes ago.

```
$ hg revert <files-touched-within-last-10-minutes>
```

On Unix systems, you get the list of all files modified within the last 10 minutes using the `find` command:

```
$ find -mmin -10
```

#### Option 3: Commit good changes, discard bad ones

Finally there is a 3rd option which works good when your bad changes did not overwrite good changes but exist next to them. Here a good strategy is to

1. only commit the good changes (using the [record](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/RecordExtension) or [crecord](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/CrecordExtension) command), and then
2. revert all remaining changes (e.g. with `hg up -r . -C`)

---

The HG-Book has more hints on [dealing with unwanted changes](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/finding-and-fixing-mistakes.html).